# MySQL: Cursor doesn't seem to ever end

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora, database-cursor

I'm working with Aurora/MySQL.  I've got a cursor, that doesn't ever seem to finish/complete.

What is really confusing me is in the examples I've seen online, I never see them set "done" or "finish" variable to one.  Below is my script.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mass_backup $$

CREATE PROCEDURE mass_backup () 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE copy_table VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR
            SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='app_prod_schema';
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;

        OPEN table_cursor;

        REPEAT
            FETCH table_cursor INTO copy_table;
            SELECT copy_table;
            SET @var1 = copy_table;
            SET @copySql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',@var1,' INTO OUTFILE S3 ''''s3://somebucket.com-work-bucket/''', @var1 , 
                    '.csv', 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY '','' LINES TERMINATED BY ''\n''' );
            SELECT @copySql;
        UNTIL done END REPEAT;
        CLOSE table_cursor;
    END $$

DELIMITER ;

CALL mass_backup()
```

Why on earth does this cursor want to run forever?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It look like that you are exporting every table to CSV from specific schema. Just check directory if files are there and compare how many files do you have vs how many tables are in schema.

Comment: @lad2025 Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.  The issue is that there are only about 25 tables, yet I see 100+ resultset tabs.  Right now I'm just trying to make sure the '@'copySql variable reads like I think it should read.

Comment: `What is really confusing me is in the examples I've seen online, I never see them set "done" or "finish" variable to one.` => `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;` /`DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;`

Comment: @lad2025 Yes, I see the handler from the copypasta I've scraped, and I assume that it's something similar to an exception handler which short circuits the REPEAT loop.  But it never seems to get triggered.

Comment: @lad2025 I think I solved it.  Somewhere along the way, those SELECTs in my REPEAT loop were messing things up.  Or maybe that's not it, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the SELECTs that I have in my repeat loop are messing up the "No more rows" handler.  I removed the REPEAT and put in a loop.  This seems to work like a charm with giving me the statements that I expect.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mass_backup $$

CREATE PROCEDURE mass_backup () 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE copy_table VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR
            SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='app_prod_schema' ORDER BY table_name;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;

        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS stmtsTable;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE stmtsTable (backupStmt varchar(200));

        OPEN table_cursor;
        curloop:
        LOOP
            FETCH table_cursor INTO copy_table;
                IF done THEN
            LEAVE curloop;
            END IF;
            #SELECT copy_table;
            SET @var1 = copy_table;
            SET @copySql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',@var1,' INTO OUTFILE S3 \'s3://somebucket/dbbackups/', @var1 , 
                    '.csv\'', ' FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\'' );
            INSERT INTO stmtsTable(backupStmt)             
            SELECT @copySql;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE table_cursor;
        SELECT * FROM stmtsTable;
END $$
```

Comment: For anyone trying to get down to the nitty gritty, the key here is the continue handler and the `IF done THEN LEAVE curloop; END IF;`